# verbose rspec be_valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I found a nice hack to output a more meaningful error message when `it { should be_valid }` fails. 
[Verbose be_valid RSpec Matcher](https://gist.github.com/820666) 
The hack overloads the be_valid with a matcher. But I'm unsure where to place this file. I tried adding it to: `.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-rails-2.11.0/lib/rspec/rails/matchers` then did bundle install but the changes did not make any difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a custom matcher, you just need to add the code to a new file in your application and require it anywhere you want it to be available. If you only have one custom matcher, I'd probably just stick it in spec/verbose_be_valid.rb and then require that in your spec_helper.rb file.